# "Represent rational numbers as two point to integers, one for the numerator and one for the denominator". What does this statement mean?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I have a problem statement which says

"A rational number is a number that can be represented as the quotient of two integers. Represent rational numbers as two point to integers, one for the numerator and one for the denominator."

What does "Represent rational numbers as two point to integers, one for the numerator and one for the denominator" means ?

Comment: No guess.  What is the source of the problem?  Is it possibly a bad translation?  Alternatively, is it possibly a programming question?

Comment: Its from a problem book on c++ which I found online. I am not sure if it's a translated version or something as there is no name but only the problem statements.

Comment: So, it's probably a programming question.  The terminology is not familiar to me, but I expect they want you to define two functions $f_i:\mathbb Q \to \mathbb Z$ such that $x=\frac {f_1(x)}{f_2(x)}$.   You can't just say "numerator" and "denominator" because you have to worry about common factors and signs.

Comment: Perhaps it meant the following:

Let $\mathbb Q:=\{(a,b) : a \in \mathbb N, b \in \mathbb N_+\} / \sim$

where $(a,b) \sim (c,d) \iff ad=bc$.

In other words, every rational number can be represented as a pair of natural numbers. If we want a unique representation, we use the fact that $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d} \iff ad=bc$, and consider all possible pairs of natural numbers up to this equivalence.

Comment: Thanks for the input fellas :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a programming problem,
my guess is that they meant
"pointers to integers".

Comment: Now I think so too! Thanks!